# Initial form field doesn't set in Django

Tags: python, django

I have following set up.

Model:

```
class Feedbacks(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    feedback = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Form:

```
class FeedbackModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedbacks
        exclude = ['user_id']
```

View:

```
@login_required
def feedbackPage(request):
    username = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackModelForm(request.POST, initial={'user_id': username})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('feedback_success')
    else:
        form = FeedbackModelForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'feedback.html', context)
```

Print(username) shows current current authenticated user ID.

During the save procedure it doesn't save user_id field (it's NULL).

I need that user_id field saved from authenticated user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is how you are setting the user id when you create the object in your view function. Your code is setting a form called 'user_id' to the user id from the request object but that won't work because you have already excluded 'user_id' in your FeedbackModelForm class.

Instead of trying to set an initial value for the form, try setting the user_id field on the object directly and then saving it manually. Like so:

views.py

```py
@login_required
def feedbackPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            feedbackObj = form.save(commit=False)  # commit=False means that the form is not saved to the database yet
            feedbackObj.user_id = request.user  # set the user to the current user
            feedbackObj.save()  # save the form to the database
            return redirect('feedback_success')
    else:
        form = FeedbackModelForm()
```

That should fix the issue. (well at least, I think it will)

Comment: I tried feedbackObj.user_id = request.user.id. I receive "Cannot assign "1": "Feedbacks.user_id" must be a "User" instance."  The feedbackObj.user_id = request.user.username couse the same error

Comment: @poputchik oh ok, that means you need to set user_id to an actual user and not just the user.id. So change this:

```feedbackObj.user_id = request.user.id```

to this:
```feedbackObj.user_id = request.user```
I'd suggest changing the name of user_id to just user to make it clearer.